# PySide open a new window, but close immediately

Tags: python, pyside

I have a question. Although some questions are similar with mine, but i cat't find how to resolve.
I create a login window, when click 'Confirm' button, hope to load a new window. But now the new window will show and close immediately.The code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import time
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import login
import moreFrame_modify

class show_login(QWidget,login.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(show_login,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = login.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def show_notepad_clk(self):  #This function will trigger a new window
        print "Hello world!"
#         farm.destroy()
        time.sleep(1)
        showMemoUI().show()

    def exit_login_show(self):
        time.sleep(.1)
        exit()
#         self.destroy()

    def create_new_user(self):
        print "Create"
        QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')


class showMemoUI(QWidget,moreFrame_modify.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(showMemoUI,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = moreFrame_modify.Ui_Form()
        print "Start show"
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        print "Show notepad UI"


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    farm = show_login()
    farm.show()
#     farm = showMemoUI()
#     farm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

login.py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'login.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Nov 12 17:25:34 2018
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(291, 207)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/a15.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(20)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(20, -1, 20, 20)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.userTxt = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.userTxt.setObjectName("userTxt")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.userTxt)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.pwdTxt = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.pwdTxt.setObjectName("pwdTxt")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pwdTxt)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.confirmBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.confirmBtn.setFont(font)
        self.confirmBtn.setObjectName("confirmBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.confirmBtn)
        self.cancelBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.cancelBtn.setFont(font)
        self.cancelBtn.setObjectName("cancelBtn")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.cancelBtn)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.regeisterBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.regeisterBtn.setFont(font)
        self.regeisterBtn.setObjectName("regeisterBtn")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.regeisterBtn)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.confirmBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), Form.show_notepad_clk)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.cancelBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), Form.exit_login_show)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.regeisterBtn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), Form.create_new_user)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Login", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "UserName", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Password", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.confirmBtn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Confirm", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.cancelBtn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Cancer", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.regeisterBtn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Add a new user", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

import myresource_rc
```

moreFrame_modify.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'moreFrame_modify.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Nov 12 17:25:38 2018
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(469, 458)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        Form.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/a11.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Form.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.frame_3 = QtGui.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(self.frame_3)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.timeEdit = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.frame_3)
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName("timeEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timeEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.addrTxt = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_3)
        self.addrTxt.setObjectName("addrTxt")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.addrTxt)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.commTxt = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_3)
        self.commTxt.setObjectName("commTxt")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.commTxt)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.frame_3)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 293, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Notepad", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Date", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Time", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Address", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Comment", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Save", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "About", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

import myresource_rc
```

Add login.py and moreFrame_Modify.py ,these two files are generated by QT designer.

Comment: share `moreFrame_modify.py` and `login.py`

Comment: the button click will trigger function 'show_notepad_clk(self)' .I hope this function will show a new window, but the new window will disappear and close immediately.

Comment: Can you show what I asked?

Comment: These two files have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have 2 errors:

- You should not use `time.sleep()` in a GUI, in the case of Qt you should use `QTimer` since `time.sleep()` freezes the GUI.
- A local variable created in a function only exists as long as the function is executed, in your case `showMemoUI` is shown and instantly eliminated, therefore the new window is not observed. The solution is to make the new window member of the class.

Using the above, the solution code is:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import login
import moreFrame_modify

class show_login(QtGui.QWidget, login.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(show_login,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.showmemoui = showMemoUI()

    def show_notepad_clk(self):  #This function will trigger a new window
        print("Hello world!")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.showmemoui.show)

    def exit_login_show(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, QtGui.QApplication.quit)

    def create_new_user(self):
        print("Create")
        QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')

class showMemoUI(QtGui.QWidget, moreFrame_modify.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(showMemoUI,self).__init__(parent)
        print("Start show")
        self.setupUi(self)
        print("Show notepad UI")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    farm = show_login()
    farm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Very perfect solution the problem，thank you very much!